# Split a payment over multiple invoices using SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Source data in table `Inv-Payments`:

| Date | Customer | Inv ID | Inv Amt | Pmt ID | Pmt Amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | ABC | Inv-1 | 500 | NULL | NULL |
| Jan 2 | ABC | Inv-2 | 1000 | NULL | NULL |
| Jan 3 | ABC | NULL | NULL | PMT-1 | 250 |
| Jan 4 | ABC | NULL | NULL | PMT-2 | 500 |
| Jan 5 | ABC | NULL | NULL | PMT-3 | 750 |

Desired output:

| Inv Dt | Customer | Inv ID | Inv Amt | Pmt Dt | Pmt ID | Pmt Amt | inv_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | ABC | Inv-1 | 500 | Jan 3 | PMT-1 | 250 | 250 |
| Jan 1 | ABC | Inv-1 | 500 | Jan 4 | PMT-2 | 250 | 0 |
| Jan 2 | ABC | Inv-2 | 1000 | Jan 4 | PMT-2 | 250 | 750 |
| Jan 2 | ABC | Inv-2 | 1000 | Jan 5 | PMT-3 | 750 | 0 |

I have tried using windowing functions `lag` and `lead` & running totals - but I am unable to figure out splitting the second payment. I can possibly write a script to loop over the invoices and payments separately, but I would rather try to do it in SQL if possible.

Please note the payment is not linked to an invoice-ID. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please explain your logic for your output in plain english

Comment: please tag your DBMS.

Comment: @eshirvana - Basically I am trying to link a payment to an invoice.  When a payment spans over 2 invoices, I am not sure how to split the amount between the invoices. Thanks.

Comment: yes but how do you match a payment with an invoice? what's the logic behind that ?

Comment: the customer ID - The payment will be applied in the chrono order. So the first Inv-1 will be partially paid from the first payment and fully paid from the second payment and the balance will be used for the next invoice [inv-2]

Comment: hmm... nothing easy come to my mind , maybe with recursive cte !

Comment: recursive CTEs are not supported in Redshift and there is a limit of 1 open cursor in their stored procedure as well, but I can use intermediary tables if it will help.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the logic here is to duplicate every row to have a second invoice.

Use the SQL UNION or UNION ALL function and add your logic for Pmt ID, Pmt Amt, inv_balance.